# UIImageView scale to fill issue

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

I have a `UIImageView` in a `UIViewController` which is loaded by `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`. I am loading the image using [Kingfisher library](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) from a URL.
The `UIImageView` is Scale to fill and aspect ratio is set to 3:4 in auto layout.
However the image loaded is corrupt in the top and left (see below)

[image: corrupt image]

The image format is `JPG` and I tried loading multiple images to check if `JPG` itself is corrupt but issue persists. However if I a load a large image that does need to scale up to fit `UIImageView` there is no issue.
I also tried using "`Aspect fill`" with no luck.

The code I use to load image is

```
self.newsImage.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: self.newsItem.imageUrl)!)
```

What could be the issue?